# tring to reduce the redux boilerplate with some utils

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was wondering if there's something wrong with the approach I'm trying in this link:
https://t.co/WSV81eDwkr

Basically the  idea is to modify only the actions file when you add a new action.
on of the Improvement I'm thinking is to recursivle merge the status passed from the actions with the reducer's state.
Let me know

Answer (score 2):

Good thinking. Unfortunately this is an anti-pattern in redux. Actions are supposed to be "pure", stateless, and non-mutating. You are accessing the state directly from an action, which is circumventing the flow of data (oldState => view => action => reducer => newState). Of course the framework is there to help you so if you find that this solution scales well with your project, it could be the way to go.

But to answer your question, it's definitely the wrong approach if you are trying to keep the Redux approach. Another issue I see is that you can't easily serialize actions so it'll likely break time traveling and the redux dev tools if you were to use them.

It's true that there's quite a bit of boilerplate involved in Redux but it's the price to pay to overcome all those CONS you listed with this new approach. Debugging the state of your application is much harder in this scenario.

Comment: thank you for your response, it's really appreciate!
My idea was based by this article
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html
where Dan use the state inside the action, so I was thinking it was legit.
maybe I should pass the old state as a parameter of the action to make it pure?
For your second point, In the end the functions are still returning a plain json  so it should be serializable (sorry, the name updateLayoutState is really bad in this case, it should be something more like createLayoutAction).
In any case, do you have any solution to remove the boilerplate?

Comment: Ah I see. The difference between his examples, in my opinion, is that he's accessing the state as a "middleware" effect kind of approach. What jumped at me about your code was that you were updating the state of your application in your action creators. If that's not what it's doing then it starts to make more sense. I think this sort of question is more appropriate in a forums than a QA site so I'll stop here, otherwise it'll get too lengthy and the question might get tagged as too general.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.
I've moved it here:
https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/an-approach-to-reduce-redux-boilerplate/3485